# Running a console app with arguments from C# - GUI Hookup Advice

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, console

(Warning: This is a C# n00b question! Trying to learn a bit of C# while making things easier for a console app I run frequently.)

I'm trying to run a console application (`consoleapp.exe`) without having to manually type in the arguments each time - The command is typically of this form:

`C:/consoleapp.exe --username (uname) --password (pass) --inputfile "c:/pathtofile/filename.xml"`

Using C# I might even be able to load up a Windows explorer file prompt, instead of having to manually type in the file path each time. How would I go about doing this?

I tried the [snippet at this link](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/run-console-app-without-dos-box.htm). I got it to work by just replacing the `ApplicationPath` with the path to my cojnsole app, and `ApplicationArguments` with the arguments shown in the format above, except *I'm not sure how to hook up the parameters with the VC# GUI tools, or to relay the output I get from the original console app back.*

Comment: A `.bat` file would probably be easier (http://tips.oncomputers.info/archives2003/0305/2003-may-04.htm).

Comment: yes, but ideally i'd like to have the luxury of being able to click a button to load a win explorer file dialog for the `--inputfile` argument - instead of externally looking for the filepath each time

Comment: I've read this question a few times more I am not sure if I understand it correctly. @Ina -- could you write (step by step) what are you doing? If `consoleapp` is an app which you develop, build and run from VS? Or it's an app your app fire from code?

Comment: `consoleapp` - app to fire from code...

Answer (score 10):

This is not answer to question above -- see comments to question above.

In **Project Properties** dialog, on **Debug** tab you can define **command line arguments** and **working directory**.

Answer (score 1):

here's some sample code of running a console app with parameters and processing the output.

```
private static Process PrepareTfProcess(string args)
{
    return new Process
                      {
                          StartInfo =
                              {
                                  CreateNoWindow = true,
                                  FileName = @"consoleapp.exe",
                                  Arguments = args,
                                  RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                  UseShellExecute = false
                              }
                      };

}

//...
using (var process = PrepareTfProcess("--param1 --param2"))
{
    while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        string str = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        // Process output lines here
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: Although I'm not exactly sure if that's what you asked about and if it helps